# Merging two lines of code into one

Tags: c#, arrays, merge

```
byte[] p = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);

byte[] p = new Byte[8]
```

I need to define the size of the array and keep the first line of code at the same time.
I get an error when I write them both, because p array is defined twice. How can I do this?

This is the code as a whole

```
public string hasher(string password, string id)
    {
        try
        {

            byte[] p = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] a6 = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(id);

            byte totVector = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                totVector = (byte)(totVector + p[i]);
            }

            byte[] a_concat = new byte[2];
            a_concat[0] = (byte)((p[6] * totVector) % 256);
            a_concat[1] = (byte)((p[7] * totVector) % 256);

            byte[] a = new byte[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                a[i] = a6[i];
            }
            a[6] = a_concat[0];
            a[7] = a_concat[1];

            byte[] h = new byte[8];
            string hashedUserPassword = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == 2) h[i] = (byte)((p[i] << 1) ^ a[i]);
                else if (i == 3 || i == 5) h[i] = (byte)((p[i] >> 2) ^ a[i]);
                else h[i] = (byte)(p[i] ^ a[i]);

                hashedUserPassword += h[i].ToString("X2");
            }

            return hashedUserPassword;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "error";
        }


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  The `GetBytes` method creates a new array the proper length and returns it.  Why do you want to redefine it?

Comment: So you actually want only the first 8 characters of the string?

Comment: Why is p defined twice?

Comment: So you want to get a byte array representing a given string and then throw that away and get a new blank byte array of size 8?  Seems pretty pointless to me.

Comment: the reason I want to define the size of the array is because, in the following lines I have a loop that runs 8 times, and it returns an "index out of range" error. So I thought that this might fix that.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to truncate the array and keep only the first 8 bytes of the original one

Comment: Please post all of your code so we can help you more.

Comment: So modify your loop to run to `p.Length`.

Comment: Modify your loop logic, not your array size

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is right here:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            totVector = (byte)(totVector + p[i]);
        }
```

The easiest fix is to not try to do 8 iterations if the array doesn't have that many items. So calculate the length first:

```
int len = Math.Min(p.Length, 8);  // limit to no more than the length
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    totVector = (byte)(totVector + p[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are encoding your string as `ASCII` this can make sense.

```
byte[] p = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            password.Substring(0, password.Length > 8 ? 8 : password.Length));
```

Comment: Now I want to hear explanation about downvote. In will be very fanny :)

Comment: Some people just want to watch the world burn

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with a couple of questions...

1. Do you want 'password' truncated to 8 characters if it's more than 8 characters?
2. What do you want to do if `password` is < 8 characters?

You could do something like this:

```
byte[] p = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0,-8}",password));
```

This will truncate `password` to 8 characters and tail pad with spaces if it's less than 8 characters.

Comment: all passwords are 8 characters so I don't want it to be truncated. I don't understand why I get the index out of range error.

Comment: @user3698687 - where do you get the index out of range error? I ran it, and as long as password is 8 characters long and id is 6 characters, it runs

Comment: Oh god, I made a stupid mistake while sending the variables to the function, it runs perfectly thanks a lot :)

Comment: You should probably do some sort of validation check on the variables before assuming that the strings are a specific length, so you don't run into those kind of problems.